# asyncData not being called on refresh in a nested route

Tags: async-await, axios, nuxt.js

I have a blog detail page, which has a asyncData call to t he blog ID requested. When the redirection happens from index to the detail page, the asyncData requests the detail, but when I refresh the detail page there is no call made. The first code is from index.vue and the the second is the nested component.

```
async asyncData() {
 const { data } = await axios.get(
  'https://calltocms.com/_/items/blog?meta=total_count%2Cresult_count&limit=50&offset=0&fields=%2A.%2A.%2A&sort=-publishing_date'
)
 return { articles: data }
}
```

```
asyncData({ params, error }) {
 return axios
  .get(
   `https://calltocms.com/_/items/blog/${+params.id}?fields=%2A.%2A.%2A`
   )
   .then(res => {
    return { post: res.data }
   })
   .catch(e => {
    error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
   })

}
```

I want the asyncData call to be made on refresh from the nested component.